# PostgreSQL 9.5 and PostGIS on OSX

Tags: postgresql-9.5, postgis, enterprisedb

I have installed [PostgreSQL 9.5 on OSX](https://www.postgresql.org/download/macosx/) using the [EnterpriseDb](http://www.enterprisedb.com/products-services-training/pgdownload#macosx) package.

How do I install PostGIS on it? The [official PostGIS OSX Page](http://postgis.net/install/) says that:

> The OSX PostgreSQL/Stackbuilder combination from EnterpriseDB has had mixed reliability. Avoid.

Are there any options to

Answer (score 0):

I would avoid the enterpriseDB version. Uninstall and install the homebrew package manager from the terminal and do `brew install postgis`.

Comment: I have had problems with brew and did not have problems with EnterpriseDb. But now you are saying that postgis does not work with EnterpriseDb. So what am I supposed to do?

Comment: If you don't have a problem - don't change:-)